# RxJS pipe Finalize operator called before Observable completed

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am going to get the user list after updating their detailed information.
First, I updated user detailed information using `this.mediaService.updateImports(): Observable<any>`
Second, I tried to display the updated user detailed information using `this.getUserList();`
By the way, `this.getUserList()` didn't show the updated user List. 
The updated user list was shown when I use `setTimeout(() => { this.getUserList(); }, 3000);` instead of `this.getUserList();`
Also, the updated user list was shown when I call `this.getUserList()` after a few seconds later.

```
this.mediaService.updateImports(
  this.momentService.momentId,
  this.momentService.moduleItemId,
  doc
).pipe(
  finalize(() => {
    this.getUserList();
    // setTimeout(() => { this.getUserList(); }, 3000);
  })
).subscribe();
```

Could you please let me know how can I display the updated user list as soon as it is updated?

Kind regards,
Jie Li.

Comment: Please include [MCVE]. What does getUserList look like?

Comment: `function getUserList() { this.guestsService.getReleations().subscribe((data: ReleationUser[]) => { this.dataSource.data = data; }); }`

Comment: Please provide the code in your question.

Comment: If using `setTimeout()` helped then the change wasn't detected by Angular's change detection. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827334/triggering-change-detection-manually-in-angular

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the multiple subscriptions, you'd need to use a higher order mapping operator like `switchMap` to map from one observable to another here. The `finalize` operator is better suited for side-effects like adjusting the loading status.

```js
this.mediaService.updateImports(
  this.momentService.momentId,
  this.momentService.moduleItemId,
  doc
).pipe(
  switchMap(() => this.guestsService.getReleations())
).subscribe(
  (data: ReleationUser[]) => this.dataSource.data = data,
  (error: any) => console.log(error)
);
```

Comment: I already tried this method but didn't work. Is there any other way?